# Get Ajax data from URL and use it

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
plot($('#pageviews'), 'line', {
  labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'],
  datasets: [
    { 
      fillColor: rgba("#404040", 0.25), 
      data: [20, 24, 28, 30, 26, 18, 16, 10] 
    }
  ]
});
```

And I have a url, "/data/stats/pageviews", which returns the JSON:

[
    { "Labels": "1", "Data": 2 },
    { "Labels": "2", "Data": 20 },
    { "Labels": "4", "Data": 20 }
  ]

I tried the following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/data/stats/pageviews',
  dataType: 'json'
}).success(function (data) {

  plot($('#pageviews'), 'line', {
    labels: data.Labels,
    datasets: [
      { 
        fillColor: rgba("#404040", 0.25), 
        data: data.Data
      }
    ]
  });

});
```

This is not working ... I think the problem is how I am using the data. Is it?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: put your code in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that using `data.Labels` does not fetch the values of all the `Label` keys in the data, because they are stored individual items in the array. Therefore, we will have to loop through each array item in your `data`, each of which is an object which we can then access the values of both the `Labels` and `Data`. A demonstration of this code is available at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/hHE2r/3/

```
var data = [ { "Labels": "1", "Data": 2 }, { "Labels": "2", "Data": 20 }, { "Labels": "4", "Data": 20 } ];

// Declare new arrays
var dataLabels = [],
    dataData = [];

// Loop through returned data
$.each(data, function(key, value){
    dataLabels.push(this.Labels);
    dataData.push(this.Data);
});

console.log(dataLabels);
console.log(dataData);
```

Therefore, in order to integrate this into your AJAX call, we can do the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/data/stats/pageviews',
    dataType: 'json'
}).success(function (data) {

    // Declare new arrays
    var dataLabels = [],
        dataData = [];

    // Loop through returned data
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        dataLabels.push(this.Labels);
        dataData.push(this.Data);
    });    

    // Draw lot
    plot($('#pageviews'), 'line', {
        labels: dataLabels,
        datasets: [{
            fillColor: rgba("#404040", 0.25),
            data: dataData
        }]
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call the ajax request and then set the plot paramaters based on what the request returns like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    url:"/data/stats/pageviews",
    dataType:'json'
    success:function(obj){
        plot($('#pageviews'), 'line', {
            labels: obj.Labels,
            datasets: [
             { 
                fillColor: rgba("#404040", 0.25), 
                data: obj.Data
             }
            ]
        });
    }
  });
```

Your JSON object that is returned must be in this format:

```
{"Labels": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"],
 "Data": [20, 24, 28, 30, 26, 18, 16, 10]
}
```

Comment: I tried something like that but didn't work ... I just updated my code ... I think the problem is how I am using the JSON data ... Is it?

Comment: Yes it is. Now that you've edited your question and posted the result of your JSON, my answer above would not work, you would have to either parse your response in javascript as terry suggest or format your response in php to return an object with your data preformatted. Ex JSON result: `{"Data":[...],"Labels":[...]}`